# Derivatives Involving Parentheses and Trig Functions

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule, transcendental-equations

$y=(\cos3)x^{2}$

If we were to take the first derivative of the equation, wouldn't we apply the product rule so that:

$y^{'}=f(x)g^{'}(x)+g(x)f^{'}(x)$, where
$f(x)=\cos3 $  , and
$g(x)=x^2$

Then,

$y^{'}=(\cos3)2x + x^{2}(-\sin 3)$
$=(\cos3)2x -(\sin 3)x^2$

However, the answer that the texbook gives is just $y=(\cos3)2x$. What am I missing?

Comment: $\cos(3)$ is just a number.  You should remember that differentiation is a [linear operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) and so for any constant $\alpha$ one has $\frac{d}{dx}[\alpha\cdot f(x)]=\alpha\cdot \frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]$ and so in particular $\frac{d}{dx}[\cos(3) \cdot x^2]=\cos(3)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}[x^2]$

Comment: Alternatively explained, the derivative of $\cos(\color{red}{3})$ with respect to $x$ is simply zero.  The derivative of $\cos(\color{red}{x})$ with respect to $x$ is $-\sin(x)$, but that is neither here nor there.

Answer (score 2):

The key is recognizing what you've chosen for $f(x)$. $f(x) = \cos{3}$ is not dependent on $x$, it's a constant value. So the derivative of $\cos{3}$ is $0$, not $\sin{3}$. Therefore, by the product rule you used, $y' = (\cos{3}) 2x - (0)x^2 = (\cos{3}) 2x$.

Alternatively, you can solve this as you would any constant $a$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}a f(x) = a \frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \cos{3}\frac{d}{dx}x^2 = (\cos{3})2x$$

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because $\cos(3)$ is a constant, the Derivative operator only affects the term $x^2$ so

$$D_x[y= \cos(3)x^2] \rightarrow D_x[y]= \cos(3)D_x[x^2] \rightarrow D_x[y]= 2 \cos(3) x$$

$$y'=2 \cos(3) x$$